# how do I display the updated database after deleting one row in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to delete the row after clicking on it. It is deleting the row from database but change is not appearing immediately on screen. It appears after closing and reopening the app.
I have used notifyDataSetChanged().

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    display();
}

public void display(){
    final DbHelper mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM "+  Contract.Entry.TABLE_NAME, null);

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    final nCursorAdapter nc = new nCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
    lv.setAdapter(nc);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            try {

            SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(Contract.Entry.TABLE_NAME, Contract.Entry.COL_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
            db.close();

            nc.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    lv.invalidateViews();

}
```

nCursorAdapter.java

```
public class nCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public nCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView first_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.namef);
    TextView last_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.namel);
    TextView ph_num = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.number);

    String fname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COL_F_NAME));
    String lname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COL_L_NAME));
    String phn = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COL_NUM));

    first_name.setText(fname);
    last_name.setText(lname);
    ph_num.setText(phn);
}
```

}

Comment: try to use adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position); Its better then notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: you need to remove the item from your list too and then call `notifyItemRemoved`

Comment: @VivekMishra can you please how to do it? I am using CursorAdapter

Comment: can you show your adapter class

Comment: @VivekMishra added to the question after editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will reload the `Activity` without any blink or animation

```
private void refresh() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

So, after delete the row call this method.